# Mysql get top products

Tags: php, mysql

Let me tell you an example from my question.
For example we have table named (order) that insert all orders and purchase to this table.

Table A (orders):

```
+--------------------------+
| CustomerKey | ProductKey |
+--------------------------+
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 597864      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro2       |
| 905479      | pro3       |
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 348965      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro3       |
+--------------------------+
```

Now i would like to order and get our Bestselling products
Query output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold  |
+-------------------------------+
| 1  | pro3       | 4           |
| 2  | pro1       | 2           |
| 3  | pro2       | 1           |
+-------------------------------+
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: This is a beginner SQL question, any tutorial should explain how to do it. SO is not a service for doing your homework.

Comment: i can't find my answer. and this is't my homework :) if you can't help me pls..

Comment: My first comment should be helpful enough for you to get started.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
select ProductKey, count(1) as numberSold from A group by ProductKey order by count(1) desc
```

The query group the same products by **ProductKey** and sum the total of sold **count(1)**.
Then, show the results ordered by the max sold to min sold.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you for you tips. I'm new on SO and in further responses I will follow this.

Comment: You should modify *this* response too - don't wait for the future.